# Third Party Lib disposes context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, sendgrid

Without the first two lines of the following, the Email is saved to the database just fine.

However, when I send the email using SendGrid's lib, an exception is thrown when the repository tries to save it, as the Context has been disposed.

`System.ObjectDisposedException`

It makes no sense to me unless the library is somehow mishandling threads or some such.

```
var response = await this._emailSender.SendEmailAsync(email);
email.ResponseStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
this._emailRepository.Save(email);
```

My workaround is to create a new context:

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext(this._options, this._applicationUserProvider);
context.Add(email);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a better way to resolve this?

Comment: What is `this` in your code? You are using Async `SendEmailAsync`, are you actually awaiting the result?

Comment: What is the exact exception message you are getting?

Comment: @Wurd, `this._emailSender` is just a wrapper around the library. Yes, I am awaiting the result - it is populated and returns the correct response.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, It's a `System.ObjectDisposedException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unless the library is somehow mishandling threads or some such.

It's an async method.  The line after `await` may run on a different thread at a later time.

The place to look is in the calling code.  If you call the method containing this line and don't wait/await the returned task, then the calling code can Dispose your DbContext while the email-sending Task is still running.

Comment: Good point.  I will double check that I am properly awaiting the call.

Comment: After some study of async/await and some refactoring, all is working well now.